# has_one and belong_to associations with the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wonder is it ok to have like 2 associations with the same table. For example:

```
class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :teams do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.references :manager, foreign_key: { to_table: 'users' }
    end
  end
end

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.references :team
    end
  end
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'manager_id'
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  has_one :child_team, class_name: 'Team' # bad name, but just for example
end
```

Or it would be better to create a join table with team_id, user_id, and member_type?

Ruby/Rails versions do not matter but let's assume Ruby is 2.7.0 and Rails is 6.0.0

Comment: I think the important question is, do you envision having other User-Team associations in the future? If so, then it would be better to create the join table now, instead of having to deal with schema/data migrations later. But if you are pretty confident that Teams will only have a Manager User and Member Users, then I think this would be fine.

Comment: @pcrglennon I can't predict that for now. Just curious is it a good practice, it looks weird for me but from the other side, I think join table with type is overengineering.

Comment: Fair enough! In cases like this, I like to think of what a future migration might look like if/when it's needed, and how you would implement and execute it Like in this case, you'd need to do a few steps (to be totally safe): a schema migration to add the join table, some code change to make sure both the new association structure and old structure work, then a data migration to populate it with associations, change the code inside the models, and then another schema migration to remove the old associations. Which is kind of a pain, in my experience!

Comment: To be fair, the steps I outlined above may be extreme and over-the-top. If you can tolerate some downtime, the migration could be much simpler (just by doing everything at once, after putting the app in maintenance mode/whatever). I'm just thinking worst case scenario, in which you can't afford to take your app down at all.

Comment: @pcrglennon It's just for demo. I am not sure I'll have any data and there would be a necessity in migrations. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Sounds good!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a technical point of view - that's perfectly fine, but be careful with possible foreign key loop in the future.

This is more a question of architecture and your predictions of how system will evolve. A many-to-many relation with a explicit join model is more flexible. For example:

1. does manager always belong to the team? with a join table it's easier to fetch "all users from the team, no matter the role" or "all the teams a person has relation to, also no matter the role"
2. if there will be other roles or multiple people at same position - join table will also come handy

Comment: It's for a demo app. I can't answer both questions, but let's assume only one manager per team and there are no positions. Actually, `From a technical point of view - that's perfectly fine` - that is what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you have seems fine.

Though a join table would be more flexible to provide more roles. This also avoids having a circular dependency in setting up teams and users.

```
class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :teams do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateTeamMembers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :team_members do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :team, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.integer :role, null: false

      t.timestamps

      # Enforce one manager per team
      t.index [:team_id],
        name: :one_manager,
        unique: true,
        where: "role = 0"
    end
  end
end

class TeamMember < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: { manager: 0, player: 1, fan: 2 }

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, through: :team_members

  has_many :team_members, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :manager, -> { where(role: :manager) }, class_name: "TeamMember"
  has_many :players, -> { where(role: :player) }, class_name: "TeamMember"
  has_many :fans, -> { where(role: :fan) }, class_name: "TeamMember"  
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_memberships, dependent: :destroy, class_name: "TeamMember"
  has_many :teams, through: :team_memberships
end
```

You could even potentially take advantage of [single table inheritance](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance) to differentiate your users by their role.

This is something you could migrate to later if necessary.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the answer. Once I used to work with a legacy project with lots of unrelated mess in the sti. Since that time I have sti allergy.